Need help to understand Date rollover logic
I am trying to understand the logic to rollback the date to previous month.
const now = new Date();
console.log(`Initial Date: ${now}`); // Initial Date: Wed Oct 23 2024 00:01:56 GMT-0500 (CST)

now.setDate(-1);
console.log(`Updated Date: ${now}`); // Updated Date: Sun Sep 29 2024 00:01:56 GMT-0500 (CST)

Here, why the Updated Date in not showing as Sep 30?
I am unable to understand the output Updated Date: Sun Sep 29 2024 00:01:56 GMT-0500 (CST)

but why not now.setDate(0)? as you are going back to September it will move back two days from September as 0 is September 30 and -1 is 29th.

When you use now.setDate(-1), you're not actually rolling back the date to the previous month. Instead, you're setting the date to the 1st day of the current month minus 1 day.
Here's how it works:

Initial Date: Let's say today is October 23, 2024.
Setting the Date: When you call now.setDate(-1), you're telling it
to set the date to the 1st of October (because the Date object
rolls back to the start of the month) and then subtract 1 day,
which results in September 29, 2024.

Use this to get the


const now = new Date();
const lastDayOfPreviousMonth = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 0);

console.log(`Last Day of Previous Month: ${lastDayOfPreviousMonth}`);



Explanation:

new Date(year, monthIndex, day): This constructor creates a new date.
The monthIndex is zero-based (0 for January, 1 for February, etc.).
now.getFullYear(): Gets the current year. now.getMonth() - 1: Gets he
previous month.


You're on the right track, but not quite correct. now.setDate(-1) sets the date to the -1th of the month, which is not the day before the first, but two days before. 0 is the day before the 1st, and -1 is the day before the zeroth day, so for 23 Oct 2024, setDate(-1) sets the date to the day before the last day of the previous month, i.e. 29 September (0 would set it to 30 September).

You can find an answer in the official documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

The setDate() method of Date instances changes the day of the month
for this date according to local time.


setDate() function does not execute relative calculation to the date stored in variable. But rather sets the actual date based on value providedl
Treat the value of setDate() function as index of an array with
dates, rather than actual day you want to subtract or add

[29 sept, 30 sept, 1 oct, .... 30 oct, 31 oct, 1 nov]
[-1,0,1,...30,31, 32]
setting date to 0 will always point you to the last day of the previous month:
const date = new Date();
// 23 oct
console.log(date.toDateString());
date.setDate(0);
// 30 sep
console.log(date.toDateString());

// important!: you have changed the month to september with setDate(0)
//so you will be looking up for an array of dates in september now
date.setDate(1);
// 1 sep
console.log(date.toDateString());

So in your example setting it to -1 will return 29th of September.
